# Freeing node in a linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, free

I'm doing some exercise with linked lists in C. And have encountered a pointer problem. I'm trying to implement the function RemoveListByIndex(list, index).
And so far I this code.

```
void RemoveNodeByIndex(struct node** head,int index) // NOT WORKING YET
{
  // Remove node list
  struct node* current = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index);
  struct node* prev    = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index-1);

  // For debugging
  PrintHRLine();
  printf("Deleting item %d from list.\n", index);
  printf("Item %d data = %d\n", index, current->data);
  PrintHRLine();
  // Change link from prev link node to the next
  prev->link = current->link;

  // Unlink node wished to delete
  current->link = NULL;
  current->data = 0;

  // Free data
  free((struct node*) current);
}
```

GetNodeByIndex function:

```
struct node* GetNodeByIndex(struct node** list, int index)
{
  // Return node by an index given
  // if error it returns NULL
  // for i < index
  //       next_node <- node.link
  //     node <- next.node
  // return next_node

  struct node* current = *list;
  int counter = 0;

  if (current)
    {
      while (current->link != NULL)
    {
      if (counter == index)
        return current;

      current = current->link;
      counter++;
    }
    }
  else
    {
      return NULL;
    }

  return NULL;
}
```

my list is structured like this:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* link;
};
```

And I call the function from my main code like this:

```
int main()
{
  struct node* head = NULL;
  struct node* edit_node = NULL;

  int i;
  edit_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  // Create a list of 10 elements
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_LIST; i++)
    {
      struct node* item = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      item->data = i;
      if (i==0)
        head = item;
      printf("(item+%d)->data = %d\n",i,i);
      if (i<SIZE_OF_LIST-1)
    {
      item->link = (item+i+1);
      printf("(item+%d->link = (item+%d+1);\n", i, i);
      printf("(item+%d adress = 0x%lx\n",i, (unsigned long int) &item+i);
    }
      else 
    {
      item->link = NULL;
      printf("(item+%d->link = NULL;\n", i);
    }
}

  // RemoveNodeByIndex(head, 5);
  // PrintListData(&head);
  edit_node->data = 1001;
  AddLastNode(&head, &edit_node);
  SearchNode(&head, 101);
  RemoveNodeByIndex(&head, 8);
  PrintListData(&head);

  // Free memory
  free(item);
  free(edit_node);
  free(head);

  return 0;
}
```

Everything seems to do fine, except that when I get to the free() call. it fails.
output:

```
===================================
Deleting item 8 from list. Located : 0x7fffd20ecad0
Item 8 data = 6
===================================
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000011b2090 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have a suspicion that I'm handling my pointer some way wrong. 
But what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have included all my source code in the following link : [SOURCE CODE](http://pastebin.com/Yt4fj2Aq)
And I've included all the output generated by program here : [OUTPUT](http://pastebin.com/7SWqcCYx)

Thanks, on advance.

Comment: Please try debugging. Or use Valgrind....

Comment: why `free((struct node*) current);` the casting is required?

Comment: If you are using linked list, doing this `current = (*(head)+index);` is not a away to find nth node.

Comment: `struct node* current = (*(head)+index);` and `struct node* prev = (*(head)+index-1);` are wrong. It only works if the elements are in successive locations in memory which is unlikely in a linked list. You need to start at the `root` and loop through `index-1` times to get to `prev` and then get `current` from its pointer.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll update the code

Comment: @Rohan I've upatede the code to get the correct node now

Comment: I can see by the output generated that the address I'm trying to free is not the correct one, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: You can handle linked lists the way you do by maintaining a pool of nodes in `item`. But you cannot `free` the nodes individually, only the whole chunk of 10. And your linked list cannot have more than ten nodes, which you must ensure. And you probably should keep an auxiliary structure that tells you which nodes are used and which aren't. And the index in the list doesn't necessariliy correspond to the item index - think about what happens if you delete item #0 - item #1 will then be the list item #0. Lastly, don't allocate memory for the `head`; it's just a pointer to an existing `item`.

Comment: @MOehm OK I'll update code, and get back you you. I have classes now and for the next 1.5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not post the complete code, but i think the issue is with `free()`.

as the man page for `free()` says

> free() frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or  realloc().   Other-
>          wise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behaviour occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

I think in your cse, the pointer to `current` is not allocated by `malloc()` or `calloc()`. by doing `(*(head)+index);` you're pointing to somewhere else.

---

EDIT:

in your code, instead of using `item = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node) * 10);`, try to allocate each `node` seperately. Also, while deleting `n`th node, the approach should be go to the `n-1`th node, get the `next` [or `link`] pointer and `free()` it.

---

EDIT 2:

How come

```
  struct node* current = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index);
  struct node* prev    = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index);
```

`current` and `prev` are same? What do you think?

Comment: No the is correct, the current is not directly allocated by malloc

Comment: Like allocating the memory one by one inside the for loop?

Comment: By changing the free call to free(prev->link); it doesn't crash anymore, but i can see i still have various bugs in my code.

Comment: yes. allocating in a loop should do fine. what other bugs you're getting?

Comment: It was just an typo I have changed prev to index-1.

Comment: When I'm allocating item in for loop one by one, how do I point to the first element created then?

Comment: keep a track of `head`. from there you can traverse through all the `node`s using the `link`, right?

Comment: wait!! are you allocating in a loop _all at a time_? that's not going to help. you need to allocate one `node`, update the `node` and the previous `node` and then you can go for next allocation. clear?

Comment: Let me show what code i have created so far, but i gotta go to class now. 

http://pastebin.com/6MSneM3A <-- This is my updated main function.. 
I have to go I'll update question after come back.

Comment: sorry but i don't have access to pastebin.

Comment: @SouravGhost Ah okay, I brought my laptop with me to class, I have updated the code in my question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64371/discussion-between-sourav-ghosh-and-mrsykkox).

Answer (score 2):

in your "RemoveNodeByIndex" function, please check the below line.

```
struct node* current = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index);
struct node* prev    = GetNodeByIndex(*(&head), index);
```

Both will have the same node and you are making NULL the current node and there is no link maintained if the current node get deleted. This can cause the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete the last node.

struct node* current = (*(head)+index); this points to the index + 1 node not index node
  struct node* prev    = (*(head)+index-1); this points to index node not index - 1.

Buddy you are trying to delete a part of memory allocated by the malloc. which i don't think is allowed.

Try to malloc each node separtely instead of aggregating 10 nodes into one malloc,

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to implement a linked list where the nodes are stored in a separate node pool, `items`. You have some misconceptions about this implementation:

- If the pool size is fixed, there should be only one allocation, namely that of 10 nodes for the pool. All other pointers - the list head, the current iterator node, the links in the nodes and temporal working nodes - should be pointers into existing memory.
- Because there is only one allocation, there should be only one `free` at the end, namely `free(items)`. The pointers passed to `free` must be the same that at one time have been returned from `malloc`. Your h´list head may change as may working pointers; you clearly can't free those.
- When you talk about indices, you talk about two different concepts here: The *item index*, which is the index of a node in the array `items` and the *list index*, which is the index in the list with the list head at index `0`.
- Because `items` is an array of nodes, you can get the node at the item index with `items + item_ix`. This doesn't work for a linked list. The advantage of a linked list is fast insertion and deletion. (Well, that's really for doubly-linked lists.) The disadvantage is slow lookup of nodes by index: You have to start counting from the head and iterate through the list.
- You pass the list head to your functions as pointer to pointer to the head node. That is only necessary if the function changes the list, for example when it deletes or adds nodes. It is not necessary when you just inspect the list, that is when you look up nodes or when you print it; a pointer to node suffices here.
- When you add or delete node, the allocated memory of `items` stays the same. For example, if your list is empty, `items` holds 10 nodes (whose data is arbitrary) regardless. You need a mechanism to tell whether a node is being used in the list or not. This may be an additional entry in `struct node` or it may be an auxiliary array.
- You create the list in a loop in `main`. A better implementation would be to have an extra function that adds nodes to a list. Of course, such a function would have to know about the node pool, because it needs to take its nodes from the pool.
- At this time, you should encapsulate the whole list logic in a struct. Instead of the head pointer, you pass a pointer to a list struct and make all changes there.

I've shown an example implementation below, which doesn't use allocation on the heap, but a fixed-size pool on the stack. The code uses hree data structures:

- The **node**s are the same as in your code.
- The **pool** is a fixed-sized pool of nodes that can be created on the stack and that should be initialised to zero in oder to work properly. The pool keeps track of available nodes with an extra array, `used`. The fixed pool size is defined with a compile-time constant.
- The **list** holds a reference to the list's head node and a reference to a pool. (Several lists may share a pool, but then the maximum total amount of nodes for these lists is fixed.) It also keeps track of the size, this is not necessary, but easy to do.

The client code in `main` accesses these structures only via functions after initialising the structs. Notice how the pool cannot overflow and how freeing nodes makes the sliots available to new nodes again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define POOL_SIZE 10

struct node {                       /* List node */
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct pool {                       /* Fixed-size node pool */
    char used[POOL_SIZE];           /* used/free markers */
    struct node data[POOL_SIZE];    /* associated nodes */
};

struct list {                       /* List structure */
    struct pool *pool;              /* Node pool reference */
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    int size;
};



/*
 *      Find an unused node and return it. If there are no unused
 *      nodes in the pool, return NULL:
 */
struct node *pool_new_node(struct pool *pool)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        if (pool->used[i] == 0) {
            pool->used[i] = 1;
            return pool->data + i;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*
 *      Mark a node in the pool as unused, effectively freeing it.
 *      Return 0 on success, -1 on error.
 */
int pool_free_node(struct pool *pool, struct node *node)
{
    int i = node - pool->data;

    if (i < 0 || i >= POOL_SIZE) return -1;
    if (pool->used[i] == 0) return -1;

    pool->used[i] = 0;
    return 0;
}

/*
 *      Append an item with value x at the tail.
 */
struct node *list_append(struct list *list, int x)
{
    struct node *node = pool_new_node(list->pool);

    if (node == NULL) return NULL;

    node->next = NULL;
    node->data = x;

    if (list->tail) {
        list->tail->next = node;
    } else {
        list->head = node;
    }
    list->tail = node;    
    list->size++;

    return node;
}

/*
 *      Return ix'th node in list or NULL.
 */
struct node *list_find_by_index(const struct list *list, int ix)
{
    struct node *node = list->head;

    if (ix < 0 || ix >= list->size) return NULL;

    while (node) {
        if (ix-- == 0) return node;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;    
}

/*
 *      Return first node with given data or NULL.
 */
struct node *list_find_by_data(const struct list *list, int data)
{
    struct node *node = list->head;

    while (node) {
        if (node->data == data) return node;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*
 *      Delete given node from list.
 */
void list_delete_node(struct list *list, struct node *node)
{
    if (node) {
        struct node **iter = &list->head;

        while (*iter) {
            if (*iter == node) {
                *iter = node->next;
                pool_free_node(list->pool, node);
                list->size--;
                return;
            }
            iter = &(*iter)->next;
        }
    }
}

/*
 *      Delete node at index from list.
 */
void list_delete_by_index(struct list *list, int ix)
{
    struct node *node = list_find_by_index(list, ix);

    if (node) list_delete_node(list, node);
}


/*
 *      Print the list items
 */
void list_print(const struct list *list)
{
    struct node *node = list->head;

    printf("%d items: [", list->size);
    while (node) {
        if (node != list->head) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}



/*
 *      Example client code
 */
int main()
{
    struct pool pool = {{0}};
    struct list list = {&pool};
    struct node *node;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list_append(&list, i);
        list_print(&list);
    }

    node = list_find_by_index(&list, 9);
    if (node) node->data = 1001;

    node = list_find_by_index(&list, 10);
    if (node) node->data = 1001;

    list_print(&list);

    node = list_find_by_data(&list, 7);
    if (node) node->data = 999;

    list_print(&list);

    list_delete_by_index(&list, 0);
    list_delete_by_index(&list, 0);
    list_delete_by_index(&list, 0);    
    list_delete_by_index(&list, 5);

    list_print(&list);

    for (i = -10; i < 0; i++) {
        list_append(&list, i);
        list_print(&list);
    }

    list_print(&list);

    return 0;
}
```